# Insertion sort using recursive algorithm in Java (no loops)

Tags: java, sorting, recursion

I am trying to make a Insertion sort using recursive algorithm, but it cannot contain any sort of iterative loop.
Here is the code I wrote; it doesn't seem to work

```
class Sort {
    public int shift(int[] a, int j, int k){
        if(j>=0 && k< a[j]){
            a[j + 1] = a[j];
            j--;
            shift(a,j, k);
        }
        return j;
    }

    public void IS(int a[], int i){
        int j, temp;
        if(i<a.length){
            j = i-1;
            temp = a[i];
            a[shift(a,j,temp)+1]=temp;
            IS(a,i+1);
        }
    }    
}
```

The `i` in IS() starts from 1.
I'm confused about my shift() method. If is use the code below, then it works. I'm trying to turn the while loop into a recursive algorithm but I always get a wrong output.

```
while (j >= 0 && temp<data[j]) {
  a[j + 1] = a[j];
  j--;
}
```

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is no evidence of any debugging performed on this code.  Please [edit] your question to show us what your debugging has uncovered, as well as a specific question about a specific line of code.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't realize. I'm fairly new to stackoverflow. I'll take it down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you start your recursion (eg) like this:

```
    int[] values = new int[] {7, 9, 1, 8, 2};
    IS(values, 0);
```

If you print the output you see that your solution is reaching the solution, but it is not quite there yet. Output for this example: `7, 1, 8, 2, 9`. Effectively, the only thing that has happened is that the `9` has shifted to the right a few times.

More shifting is needed. You can do that by calling `IS` several times. This is dead-ugly from a performance perspective, but it works:

```
public void metaIS(int[] a, int i) {
    IS(a, 0);
    if (i < a.length) {
        metaIS(a, i + 1);
    }
}
```

That is, call IS 5 times if the array is 5 numbers long, and all is good: `1, 2, 7, 8, 9`

By the way, it might be a good idea to rename the method. When people hear `IS`, recursive problem solving is not the first thing that comes to their minds. And a common convention is to start method names with non-capitals.